# cakephp not loading css,js bad port

Tags: cakephp

I can't load css,js files on my local machine. website is running on port 8080. 
Css,js files are loadning from bad port. URL/css/index.css is not loaded. When I add right port manualy to  URL:8080/css/index.css  file is load right. How do I set right port?

My htacces in web directory.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

in app directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

in webroot directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

mod_rewrite is enabled on xampp server

Thanks for help

Comment: What makes you think it tries to load the resources on the wrong port? By default, it loads all resources from the same domain/port as used by the app itself, unless you specifically set an absolute path to another location.

Comment: Page has this url "application:8080" when I find css file in debuger and right click -> open new tab, then url css file is "application/css/index.css" and file is not found. When I manualy include port to "application:8080/css/index.css" file is found. I therefore think it is wrong port

Comment: i found out that css files and other files  are loading from application:80/ source. How it is possibly which url is application:8080 ?

Comment: Finaly in app/Controller/AppController function url() I add ":8080" to  return 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':8080'.Router::url('/'); and work.